# Monotonicity of $f(x,y)=x+y-xy , 0\leq x,y\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

If $(x,y)\leq (u,v)$ then prove or disprove $f(x,y)\leq f(u,v)$

Obviously $x+y\leq u+v$ and $xy\leq uv$ but $-xy \geq -uv$

Comment: How can you order the elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What do you mean by (x,y)≤(u,v)?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Factorize given equation as :

$$f(x,y)=x+y-xy=-(x-1)(y-1)+1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1-y\geq0$ as $y\leq1$. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=1-x\geq0$ as $x\leq1$. Hence $f$ is increasing in both its arguments